What is this worm like creature
What is it? It moves like a worm. The things on the body are some seeds.




It is found in Germany near Düsseldorf. It is 12:30 on 19.07.2024
It is 1cm long and 0.2 cm wide and high
The source is the trash can where more were found

You seem to indicate that it's half as thick as it is long, but the pictures tell a different story. Could you [edit] to clarify.

This bears resemblance to Calci worms (also known as Black Soldier Fly Worms).
https://kimmyfarm.com/en/black-soldier-fly/larvae
Hope this helps :)

It doesn't look like a Hermetia illucens maggot. A 1-cm black soldier fly would have a very characteristic appearance: dorso-ventrally compressed pigmented body with a pointed head. But it's certainly does look like a fly larva.
